# Splitting a String but still displaying all elements

Tags: java

i'm trying to split up a string into words and symbols and display them all at the end in chronological order. Currently using the `.split()` function to store each word into an array, however the output is not quite what i'm looking for. Should I be using another function?

```
 String strInput = "{cat+dog[mouse/snake";
    String[] strSplit = strInput.split("[+*{/=-]");

    for(String word : strSplit)
    {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
```

Current output:

```
cat
dog[mouse
snake
```

Desired output:

```
cat
+
dog
[
mouse
/
snake
```

Essentially keeping the text intact and sending all symbols into a separate element in the array.

Comment: But you want to omit the "{"?

Comment: Your expectations don't match the desired output. You want two output array or one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With:

```
String[] strSplit = strInput.split("\\b");
```

where `\\b` - is a word boundary you will get following output:

```
{
cat
+
dog
[
mouse
/
snake
```

Answer (score 0):

you can adapt your regex "((?<=[+*{\[/=-])|(?=[+*{\[/=-]))"

```
String strInput = "{cat+dog[mouse/snake";
String[] strSplit = strInput.split("((?<=[+*{/=-])|(?=[+*{/=-]))");

for(String word : strSplit)
{
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

your output will look like

```
{
cat
+
dog
[
mouse
/
snake
```